# Windows Server 2022 HyperV / Ubuntu 20.04 and 22.04 / Processor compatibility mode/ "can't allocate initrd"

Tags: boot, kernel, hyper-v

When running Ubuntu 20.04 or 22.04 on Windows Server 2022 HyperV with `Processor compatibility mode`[^1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/virtualization/hyper-v/manage/processor-compatibility-mode-hyper-v) enabled the Gen v2 VM won't boot and stops with "can't allocate initrd"[^2](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-server-for-it-pro/server-2022-ubuntu-20-04-quot-can-t-allocate-initrd-quot/m-p/3116902) error.

Even the normal `generic` kernel don't work. Using a Gen v1 VM works fine.

Without enable `Processor compatibility mode` you can't do live migration to different servers.  So this blocks me from upgrading my Windows 2019 servers to Windows 2022 servers.

This happens on a System with a `AMD Ryzen 5 3600` but not on a `AMD Ryzen 7 5700G`.

The kernel panic is:

```
VFS: Cannot open root device "(null)" or unknow-block(0,0): error -6
```

Tried now from grub cmd.
Reproduced via ubuntu server live cd `ubuntu-20.04.4-live-server-amd64.iso`
Secure boot is disabled.

```
> set root=(cd0)
> linux /casper/vmlinux
> initrd /casper/initrd
error: can't allocate initrd
```

Comment: From your question. So this blocks me from upgrading my 2019 servers to 2022 What does this mean are these versions of something?

Comment: Updated. It's blocking Windows Server Upgrade.

Comment: I'm able to see the kernel panic, screenshot:
https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/image/serverpage/image-id/456912iE4B5951E3B8236E3/image-dimensions/2500?v=v2&px=-1

Comment: Have you tried to upgrade the Windows server before loading the Ubuntu stuff?

Comment: No, this server was freshly installed with windows server 2022. It has all available updates installed.

Comment: This hapens when booting the default command from `ubuntu-20.04.4-live-server-amd64.iso`

Comment: Tried now from grub cmd

```console
set root=(cd0)